# How to line my input boxes horizontaly like in the image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to do is make list of contact number form registration just like in the picture.

http://s38.photobucket.com/user/eloginko/media/number_zps5e6e5445.png.html

My problem is the form is making a newline after a new form. I want to make a copy just like in the picture. Can anyone help me, I'm using bootstrap 3.

current output: http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/79/

```
<label>Contact Numbers * </label> <br /> <br />
                    <div class="alert alert-info">Please provide at least one contact number information. </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label class="pull-right" id="myText"> Home</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            +<input class="form-control" value="63" size="6" type="text" maxlength="6" id="inptboxCountryCodehomeContactNumber" width="40" style="width:30px" name="homeContactNumberCountryCode">
                            -<input  class="form-control" value="" type="text" size="5" maxlength="6" id="inptboxAreaCodehomeContactNumber" width="50" style="width:40px" name="homeContactNumberAreaCode">
                            -<input  class="form-control" value="" type="text" size="null" maxlength="30" id="inptboxhomeContactNumber" name="homeContactNumber" width="80" style="width: 80px">
                            <p class="help-block ">Country Code - Area code - Tel. Number <br> Ex. +63-02-1234567</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label class="pull-right" id="myText"> Office</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            +<input class="form-control" value="63" size="6" type="text" maxlength="6" id="inptboxCountryCodeofficeContactNumber" width="40" style="width:30px" name="officeContactNumberCountryCode">
                            -<input  class="form-control" value="" type="text" size="5" maxlength="6" id="inptboxAreaCodeofficeContactNumber" width="50" style="width:40px" name="officeContactNumberAreaCode">
                            -<input  class="form-control" value="" type="text" size="null" maxlength="30" id="inptboxofficeContactNumber" name="officeContactNumber" width="80" style="width: 80px">
                            <p class="help-block ">Country Code - Area code - Tel. Number <br> Ex. +63-02-1234567</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label class="pull-right" id="myText"> Mobile</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            +<input class="form-control" value="63" size="6" type="text" maxlength="6" id="inptboxCountryCodemobileContactNumber" width="40" style="width:30px" name="mobileContactNumberCountryCode">
                            -<input  class="form-control" value="" type="text" size="5" maxlength="6" id="inptboxAreaCodemobileContactNumber" width="50" style="width:40px" name="mobileContactNumberAreaCode">
                            -<input  class="form-control" value="" type="text" size="null" maxlength="30" id="inptboxmobileContactNumber" name="mobileContactNumber" width="80" style="width: 80px">
                            <p class="help-block ">Country code - Network Code - Mobile Number <br> Ex. +63-987-6543210</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you think something like this http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/80/ ?

Just add the following to your css:

```
.form-control {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This displays the input like inline-block so do not wrap the new line. But if you would like to stay another inputs not changed, just add some other class next to `form-control` and set the property to this new class.

Answer (score 0):

```
.col-sm-3 input {display: inline;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/85/